# A continued fraction involving prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, limits, continued-fractions

What is the limit of the [continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions)
$$\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{5+\cfrac{1}{7+\cfrac{1}{11+\cfrac{1}{13+\cdots}}}}}}\ ?$$

Is the limit algebraic, or expressible in terms of e or $\pi$? What is the fastest way to approximate the limit?

Comment: Does the sequence $2,3,5,7,11,13,\dots$ consist of all prime numbers?

Comment: @Angela Richardson: Are you sure that it is convergent? Also, can you really use the expression of continued fractions to express a complex number such as $i$? Maybe I am missing something here, but I am a little confused. Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: @awllower: it converges by [Sleszynski-Pringsheim](http://books.google.com/books?id=zUUgs4BgcgoC&pg=PA129).

Comment: @awllower: It is convergent by the Śleszyńsky-Pringsheim's Theorem. The continued fraction $\mathbf{K}(a_{n}/b_{n})$ converges if for all $n$ 
    $$\left\vert b_{n}\right\vert \geq \left\vert a_{n}\right\vert +1.$$

Comment: Reference: Chapter I, Theorem 4.1 of *Continued fractions with applications* by Lisa Lorentzen and Haakon Waadeland.

Comment: It's pretty easy to see that it converges without any theorems whose proof is not obvious.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations.

Comment: +1 I was curious myself and did a little math with the primes < 100,000.  Excel gives 0.4323320871859030 which is off by the last two digits. Then I found this question.

Comment: Has anything new been found about this continued fraction since this post was last active?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As I've noted in the comments, the [Śleszyński-Pringsheim Theorem](http://books.google.com/books?id=zUUgs4BgcgoC&pg=PA129) guarantees that this continued fraction converges to a finite value (since the prime numbers are always greater than or equal to $2$).

[This arXiv preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4015) gives an approximate value $s$ for the continued fraction whose partial denominators are prime numbers:

$$s=0.43233208718590286890925379324199996370511089688\dots$$

which the author computed with PARI/GP. He notes that the Plouffe inverter does not at all recognize this constant.

---

Here's some *Mathematica* code for computing the constant to `prec` or so significant figures:

```
prec = 500;
y = N[2, prec + 5]; c = y; d = 0; k = 2;
While[True,
  p = Prime[k];
  c = p + 1/c; d = 1/(p + d);
  h = c*d; y *= h;
  If[Abs[h - 1] <= 10^(-prec), Break[]];
  k++];
N[1/y, prec]
```

which yields the result `0.43233208718590286890925379324199996370511089687765131032815206715855390511529588664247730234675307312901358874751711021925473474173059981681532525370102846860319246045704466728602248840679362020193843643798792955246786129609763893526940277522319731978458635595794036202066338633654544895108909659715862787332585763686200183679952128087865043794610126643260422526400822552675221511335417037835319471839444535578027072057047898703982387228841680143293913635134426277200532815721973910424896503203478507`

Comment: For purposes of computation, you can use [Lentz-Thompson-Barnett](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47453/56127#56127).

Comment: The OEIS has it, though: http://oeis.org/A084255

Comment: @J.M. can you calculate this for twin prime pairs instead of the prime (To a certain extent)...as its irrationality will prove the twin prime conjecture

Comment: @Shivam, one can certainly compute a numerical approximation of the constant you want to a pile of digits, but proving irrationality with it just seems rather unlikely.

Comment: @J.M.ain'tamathematician Since the continued fraction goes on to infinity, given that prime numbers are infinite, isn't this an indication that the number is irrational, like `φ = (1;1,1,1,1,1,...)`, for example ? Not sure if this constitutes a proof though.

Comment: @milia this is proof that the number is irrational. if it were rational, it would have a finite continued fraction representation, but the primes are not finite, so the continued fraction representation is not finite, so the number is irrational

Comment: @wyboo thanks, that's a good argument for the specific continued series. But what about φ ? Its continued fraction representation doesn't contain prime numbers, since `1` isn't considered a prime number. How do we know that `(1;1,1,1,1,...)` doesn't stop after many billions of ones proving in effect rationality of φ ?